# How to populate the activity.from.properties in Bot Framework?

Tags: botframework

We currently have a Bot deployed on our own server and have successfully connected a website to this using the Direct Line channel. Our aim is to be able to pass through a user data form the client to the bot through this channel. After some searching around on the internet, it seems the best way to pick this up is through the activity, like so:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]Activity activity)
    {

        var testy = activity.From.Properties;
        var firstname = activity.From.Properties["firstname"];
```

With our JavaScript as follows:

```
<script>
  const params = BotChat.queryParams(location.search);
  const user = {
    id: '1234', name: 'Rich', firstname: 'Ricardo', lastname: 'Griffiths',
  };
  const bot = {
    id: params['botid'] || 'botid',
    name: params['botname'] || 'botname'
  };

  window['botchatDebug'] = params['debug'] && params['debug'] === 'true';

  BotChat.App({
    bot: bot,
    locale: params['locale'],
    resize: 'window',
    user: user,
    directLine: {
      secret: params['s'],
      domain: params['domain'],
      webSocket: params['webSocket'] && params['webSocket'] === 'true' // defaults to true
    }
  }, document.getElementById('BotChatGoesHere'));
</script>
```

Unfortunately we're always getting **null** in **activity.from.name** when ideally we would like to capture the firstname that was is being passed.

Comment: Are you sure it isn't just the first connection (ConversationUpdate) event where you're not seeing the properties field set correctly? I ask because I've set up your code and it seems to work properly at the moment, if not, I can at least post what I've got running.

Answer (score 0):

> we're always getting **null** in **activity.from.name** when ideally we would like to capture the firstname that was is being passed.

As Mark B mentioned in comment, please check if you did retrieve user data from `activity.From.Properties` in a **conversationUpdate** activity.

I do a test to retrieve user information that you passed from JavsScript web chat client in [message activities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-activities?view=azure-bot-service-3.0#message), which works for me.

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]Activity activity)
{
    if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
    {
        var testy = activity.From.Properties;
        var firstname = activity.From.Properties["firstname"].ToString();
        var lastname = activity.From.Properties["lastname"].ToString();
        var name = activity.From.Name;


        await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new Dialogs.RootDialog(name, firstname, lastname));

    }
    else
    {
        HandleSystemMessage(activity);
    }
    var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    return response;
}
```

***Test result:***

[image]

***Note:***

If you’d like to get user data before user send a **message** activity, you can try to use [the backchannel mechanism](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat#the-backchannel).